# Itertools Groupby gives an Unexpected Result

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have two Lists

say

```
finalblobfpost1=['ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_14082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_14082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_15082020.txt']
```

With Same Dates for "K1_SS_ALM"

```
finalblobfpost2=['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_15082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_16082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_16082020.txt']
```

With different Dates from "K1_SS_ALM"

**i need to groupby with K1_SS_ALM and K1_AB_KIL (re.findall("\w+/\w+/\d+/(.*?)_\d+_\d+.txt", text))**

Mycode so far:

```
finalblobfpost1=['ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_14082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_14082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_15082020.txt']
keyf = lambda text: (re.findall("\w+\/\w+\/\d+\/(.*?)\_\d+_\d+.txt", text)+ [text])[0].strip()
h=[list(items) for gr, items in groupby(sorted(finalblobfpost1), key=keyf)]
print(h)
```

**Result is -Good-Enough-Expected**

```
[['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_15082020.txt', 'ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt'], ['ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_14082020.txt',
'ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_14082020.txt']]
```

Code:2

```
finalblobfpost2=['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_15082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_16082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_16082020.txt']
keyf1 = lambda text: (re.findall("\w+\/\w+\/\d+\/(.*?)\_\d+_\d+.txt", text)+ [text])[0].strip()
h1=[list(items) for gr, items in groupby(sorted(finalblobfpost2), key=keyf1)]
print(h1)
```

the result is: **Not Expected**

```
[['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt'], ['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_15082020.txt'], ['ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_16082020.txt'], ['ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_16082020.txt']]
```

**Expected is:**

```
[['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_16082020.txt'],['ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_16082020.txt','ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt']]
```

It didn't group the keywords. Is anything wrong with regex or i am doing anything wrong?

Kindly Advise please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list needs to be sorted by the same key function as used in groupby!

try this:

```py
h1=[list(items) for gr, items in groupby(sorted(finalblobfpost2, key=keyf1), key=keyf1)]
```

Only difference is the `key=keyf1` in the call to sorted

Output (same as expected):

```
[['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt', 'ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_16082020.txt'], ['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_15082020.txt', 'ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_16082020.txt']]
```

This is explicitly written in the [docs for `groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The operation of groupby() is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It
> generates a break or new group every time the value of the key
> function changes (which is why it is usually **necessary to have sorted
> the data using the same key function**).

Comment: Ok Then why for the first list it was working fine?

Comment: @user11646543 becuase of the datestamp part after `ABC/XYZ/`, it was ordered in the same way as sorting by the key function, by chance...

Comment: @user11646543 if you doubt it, see my edit with ref to the docs...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Khther/1)

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

print(
    [list(v) for _, v in groupby(finalblobfpost1,
                                 key=lambda x: re.search("\w\d+_\w{2}_\w{3}", x).group())]
)
```

---

```
[['ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_222222_14082020.txt', 'ABC/XYZ/16082020/K1_SS_ALM_111111_14082020.txt'], ['ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_444444_15082020.txt', 'ABC/XYZ/15082020/K1_AB_KIL_333333_15082020.txt']]
```

Comment: Its working but not everytime \w{3} will not come its dynamic i tried \w+ insted \w{3}. Its not working.Can you suggest me a dynamic way.

Comment: you could use ``\w\d+_\w{2}_[A-Za-z]{3,}`` which matches any word character with len greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: Perfect!! Could you please advise me why that my code was not working?Because of? just curious.